# Could not get unknown property 'testSourceDirs' for object of type org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

when i run the app i got error of

Could not get unknown property 'testSourceDirs' for object of type org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error. I had to delete JUnit dependencies from 'build.gradle' file.I also removed test .java and .class files along-with their directories. After syncing the gradle, the error was gone. You can try these steps after backing up files. After that, you can try reintroducing updated dependencies and test files. Hope it helps.

Comment: not helped in my case, but good suggestion